# Reactjs: Have one select menu set the value of another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is using react. **The problem in a nutshell is that I have two select menus in a form (as part of the same component) and I want selecting one to set the options of the other.**

One select shows months and one shows days in that selected month. Depending on which month is selected the days should show the correct number for that month (so 31 days in the days select if "January" is selected in month, 28 if "February" and so on).

I cannot get the initial value to change in response to the select. I can log the correct value but what actually appears in the days select never updates from its initial state.

Some code...

I trigger with:

```
<select defaultValue="Jan" onChange={() => { setMonthNumber(this.refs["month"]["value"]) }} ref="month">
```

`setMonthNumber` is an action:

```
export const setMonthNumber = (monthNumber) => {
   store.dispatch({type:'GUEST_INFORMATION_SET_MONTH', message:monthNumber});
}
```

The reducer that handles that action is:

```
const initialState = {
    currentMonth: "Jan"
};

const guestInformationEditReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    let localState = merge({}, state);

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GUEST_INFORMATION_SET_MONTH':
            localState.currentMonth= action.message;
            return localState;
    }

    return state
};

export default guestInformationEditReducer;
```

I aggregate my reducers and in that file I set (leaving out other reducers):

```
export default {
    guestInformationEditComponent: guestInformationEditReducer
}
```

and then in my component (named GuestInformationEdit) I connect things with:

```
const getGuestInformationComponentProps = state => {
    return {
        month: state.guestInformationEditComponent.currentMonth
    }
}

export default connect(getGuestInformationComponentProps)(GuestInformationEdit);
```

In my component's render method I access the value with:

```
const days = this.getDaysFromMonth(this.props.month);
```

`getDaysFromMonth` is simply a switch that builds a collection of jsx `options` like:

```
days.push(<option key={stringNum} value={stringNum}>{stringNum}</option>);
```

so that I end up with an array of options with the correct values depending on the selected month. This all works (logging shows the correct values). My problem... when I add `{days}` to my jsx like so:

```
<select defaultValue="1">
    {days}
</select>
```

I only ever get 31 days, the value set by the `initialState` in the reducer. It never changes in the view in spite of changing in any console logs I may try. Why? What am I doing wrong/missing? Also, is all of this really necessary for such a change? It seems wickedly complex for such a simple thing.

---

**edit

In my component I have this outputting the selects:

```
 <BootstrapFormGroup model="guestModel.BirthMonth" classes="col-xs-12 col-md-1 extra-four-percent" formLabel="Birth Month">
    <select defaultValue="Jan" onChange={() => { setMonthNumber(this.refs["month"]["value"]) }} ref="month" className="form-control">
        <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
        <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
        <option value="March">March</option>
        <option value="April">April</option>
        <option value="May">May</option>
        <option value="June">June</option>
        <option value="July">July</option>
        <option value="Aug">Aug</option>
        <option value="Sept">Sept</option>
        <option value="Oct">Oct</option>
        <option value="Nov">Nov</option>
        <option value="Dec">Dec</option>
    </select>
</BootstrapFormGroup>
{days}
<BootstrapFormGroup model="guestModel.BirthDay" classes="col-xs-12 col-md-1 extra-four-percent" formLabel="Birth Day">
    <select defaultValue="1" className="form-control">
        {days}
    </select>
</BootstrapFormGroup>
```

See those two instances of `{days}`? With my above code the first one updates correctly in response to onChange of the month select, the second one does nothing except display the initial state and then never update.